# Transforming a set of conditions with both equalities and inequalities using linear transformations

Tags: list-manipulation, inequalities

I wish to Transform a set of conditions, containing both equalities and inequalities, by using a kind of "change of variable" on the constrained variables. The change is straightforward (it is a sum of two variables), but I am not able to deal with inequalities. I have a function that does a calculation and outputs a list of conditions that looks as follows:

```
(x[1]==0&&x[2]==0&&x[3]==1/3&&x[4]==2/3)||
(x[1]==0&&x[2]==1/7&&x[3]==0&&x[4]==6/7)||
(x[1]==0&&0<x[2]<1/7&&x[3]==1/3 (1-7 x[2])&&x[4]==2/3 (1+2 x[2]))
```

In the above, the three sets of conditions need to be transformed into a new set of conditions for output where a=x[3]+x[4] and b=x[2]+x[4] for each of the three cases. So far, my attempt revolved around using replacements and I wrote the following:

```
repl = List @@@ List @@ expr /. Equal[a_, b_] :> a -> b
```

which produces the following output:

```
{{x[1] -> 0, x[2] -> 0, x[3] -> 1/3, x[4] -> 2/3}, {x[1] -> 0, x[2] -> 1/7, x[3] -> 0, x[4] -> 6/7,}, {x[1] -> 0, 0 < x[2] < 1/7, x[3] -> 1/3 (1 - 7 x[2]), x[4] -> 2/3 (1 + 2 x[2])}}
```

I can then use this in a replacement, and the code looks as follows:

```
expr = (x[1] == 0 && x[2] == 0 && x[3] == 1/3 && x[4] == 2/3) ||
(x[1] == 0 && x[2] == 1/7 && x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 6/7) ||
(x[1] == 0 && 0 < x[2] < 1/7 && x[3] == 1/3 (1 - 7 x[2]) && x[4] == 2/3 (1 + 2 x[2]));

repl = List @@@ List @@ expr /. Equal[a_, b_] :> a -> b;
{a == x[2] + x[4], b == x[3] + x[4]} /. repl
```

This "works" as long as my conditions are equal, but with inequalities, the replacement is not really feasible as such. What I would like, for this inequality, is something that would reduce the sum and include the inequality. For example, a==x[2]+x[4], by using the third set of conditions, can be written {1/7<a<1/3 && a==1/3(1-4 x[2])}. The idea is that I do not control exactly what is in expr, since it is the output of another function, so I want to be able to do this in a generic fashion rather than the ad-hoc algebra I had to do to arrive at this conclusion. How can I achieve this?